# Does idiomatic Haskell try to eliminate pair operations fst and snd, as it does head,init,tail etc?

Tags: haskell

Here is a function that doesn't sit right with me, I'm thinking I need to get rid of the fst.

```
flagHolidays :: [(C.Day,Availability)] -> Handler [(C.Day,Availability)]
flagHolidays dayPairs = do
   let days = map fst dayPairs
       yepNope = Prelude.map isHoliday days
       availability = Prelude.map flagAvailability yepNope
   return $ Prelude.zip days availability
```

The only way I can think to do it is a very ugly pattern match, along the lines of `(x,y):(xs,ys)`. Does the removal of `fst` make sense? If so, what's the best way to pattern-match this list of pairs?

Comment: `dayPars` has type `[(C.Day, Availability)]`. You can't call `fst` on it. Did you paste the right code?

Comment: Unrelated: This is a pure function. There is no need to have it in the `Handler` monad. As you saw [in your other question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8043437/how-does-one-inspect-values-inside-the-handler-monad-in-ghci), having functions like this run in a monad needlessly only makes them difficult to test. You should rather define it as a pure function and lift it when necessary.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Make the function pure and

```
flagHolidays = map (second $ flagAvailability . isHoliday)
```

And to answer the actual question, unless passed as an argument fst and snd are rarely used.

[Edit] Hmmm, I was a bit hasty writing that.  It's wrong.  You're passing in a list of pairs and never use the second component of the pair.  Corrected, but in the same vein (and now using `fst`):

```
flagHolidays = map ((id &&& flagAvailability . isHoliday) . fst)
```

Comment: `fst` and `snd` are sometimes useful for writing pointfree code that deals with tuples.

Answer (score 21):

The reason `head`, `tail` and `init` aren't used in idiomatic haskell code is that they aren't total functions - some inputs cause an error to occur. Passing an empty list to any of those functions causes an empty list exception.

`fst` and `snd` don't have this problem, as there is no input you can pass to those functions that will cause an exception. So there is no reason to try and avoid those functions.

Your function can be written better (the other comments give good details about this), but it isn't due to the use of `fst` or `snd`.

Answer (score 3):

`dayPairs` is a list of pairs, so `days` ought to be `map fst dayPairs`. And that's one place where using `fst` is idiomatic, as an argument to a higher order function. Apart from that, it's mainly used to defer evaluation of pairs when the author forgot about lazy patterns.

Answer (score 3):

I think you are correct, in that the way you are doing this doesn't seem particularly idiomatic.

Errors aside, there are lots of better ways.  As a couple of examples (probably not optimal, but still significantly more readable), you can use a lambda in your map:

```
return $ map (\(d,a) -> (d, flagAvailability $ isHoliday a)) dayPairs
```

or you can use a list comprehension:

```
return [(day, flagAvailability $ isHoliday a) | (day,a) <- dayPairs]
```

There may be some clever way to make the central mapping entirely point-free, but even so it might not be worth it -- either of the above expressions makes the operation fairly clear.  However, I think eliminating the variable `dayPairs` might be an improvement:

```
flagHolidays = return . map (\(d,a) -> (d, flagAvailability $ isHoliday a))
```

Comment: Don't forget about the wonderful combinators from `Control.Arrow`: `return $ map (second (flagAvailability . isHoliday)) dayPairs`